# How to run a corn job from 9:30am to 4pm for every half an hour

Tags: node.js, cron, cron-task, node-cron

I want a expression for cron job which is going to run every half hour starting at 9:30am to 4:00pm from monday to friday.

`cron.schedule('30,*/30 9-15 * * 1-5', async() => { function() });`

my Cron job is running every half an hour between 9:30 to 3:59
but I want it run at the start of 9:30 and runs on the end of 4:00pm`your text